# An empty tab is displayed having called innerHTML in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, innerhtml

Having migrated form frames to DIVs to exchange content on the fly using innerHTML :
in Chrome and Microsoft Edge this does work very well but in Firefox (61.0.2 
 64-Bit) a new empty tab is created (about:blank) and displayed while the content has been changed on the main page!
What to do to avoid this?

Can be reproduced at 
http://www.w-medlitsch.at/MyPhotoHomePage/de/index.html
when selecting a photo galary at the left navigation area.

some lines:

```
var tableText =  "<div id=\"galery\" class=\"galeryDiv\"> <table class=\"galeryPhotos\" id=\"galeryPhotos\" >";
......
......
tableText = tableText + "</tr></tbody></table>";
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = tableText;
```

Comment: Your `div#galery` seems unclosed. Setting `innerHTML` to invalid HTML like this will probably yield unpredictable results.

Comment: Also, why are you using a table element here? Seems like a table is not the correct structure for a photo gallery.